# Seeking tutorials online explaining how to draw squares (having specific length) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, editing, references, drawing

I need to produce in QGIS a square having a specific dimension (1km x 1km). First I created a new polygon layer, but when I start editing through the Advanced editing tool, the program crashes. I guess that there is something wrong in my procedure.

Beside that tool, does the 3.x version (I'm using Madeira) allow me to create such squares using another method?

Comment: Your layer should be in a CRS that uses meters as its units. If it's not, create a new layer that is.

Answer (score 10):

When you try to create a new polygon, you can use the Advanced Digitizing, Remember the tool don't work with geographic coordinates.

1. Click in **Toogle Editing**.
   [image]
2. Click in **add polygon feature**.[image]
3. Click in **Enable advanced digitizing tools**. [image]
4. In Advanced Digitizing Menu, with **d = 1000** (meters, I suppose is meters, that depend of you coordinate reference), and block with this tool. [image]
5. finaly, play with the coordinates in **a** section.

[image]

The result will see like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried several times but unfortunately I cannot finish the procedure, first, I cannot create the square (I have to write the coordinates x,y first), then, even if I produce a sort of polygon, then the program always stop working. I am using EPSG 3003. I wonder if it is a problem linked to version 3.4.